# Rails 4 preprocessing coffee.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, preprocessor

So I have a `app/assets/javascript/sites.js.coffee.erb` file.

There I do:

```
#lots of stuff
formData: '<%= @s3_direct_post[:fields] %>',
#and more stuff
```

which ends in:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

which seems to suggest that rails is NOT preprocessing the erb file. I tried leaving out the .erb extension, leaving `app/assets/javascript/sites.js.coffee`, but that didn't help either.

How does correct rails 4 preprocessing work???
I'm confused as the sites_controller correctly creates the `@s3_direct_post` object,
and it can be used in `app/views/sites/upload.html.erb` just fine...

Comment: Actually it seems to suggest that it actually DOES preprocess, but the object is nil for some reason...but I can access it in the view...???

Comment: looks like @objects are not available in my coffeescript...

Comment: looking at the docs http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb I am starting to suspect that's not even possible, just only helpers are allowed?

Comment: Why are you adding `.erb` files in your `/assets/` directory? If your `sites_controller` action responds to a JS format then you could add a `[action].js.erb` file in your views, otherwise, separate your JS logic from your Rails logic.

Comment: @mmichael RoR is not my strongest skill, and the little I know actually dates to 2.3x 3.0.x times...I am happy for your recommendation, I'll try that. I thought all javascript stuff would go into /assets ....

Comment: You're right that javascript files go into the `/assets` directory but `.js.erb` files are different (in the scope of Rails apps) as they are meant to be stored in your `views` directory and are rendered by your controller actions. For example, let's say you have an `update_with_js` action that `responds_to` the JS format. You could then have a corresponding `update_with_js.js.erb` file in your view that gets rendered by your controller action.

Comment: Not sure that's my situation though. I have a jquery-fileupload thing. I've tried the myriads of gems and none suits my needs (I need users to be able to select files to be uploaded prior to the upload). I initiate the widget which will upload directly to S3: `$("#fileupload").fileupload({ formData: '<%= @s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>' })` that's where I hoped to be able to pass that data. From this example: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails#cross-origin-support .This should just be a js file loaded for the html view...

Comment: I imagine you have a view that allows your users to select the files they wish to upload (to S3). In that view, you probably [should] have a form that sends a request to your controller to actually process the files and save them to S3. Your controller (along with any methods in your models) should have the logic to process the files and save them to S3. Post-processing, you can render some type of response or notice (or anything really) from your controller by calling something like `respond_to { |format| format.js { render partial: 'path_to_js_erb_file' } }`.

Comment: Do you have `@s3_direct_post` set in your controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found answers which I implemented :)

http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript